# what is list<> and fetch combo in c#

Tags: c#, .net

While viewing some code on an application I'm working on I see code that looks like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Entity
{
    public interface Itest: Iinfo
    {
        List<Entity> Fetch(int ID, 
                                    string Name, 
                                   string StateId);
    }
}
```

I know what List<> is and where it comes from (`System.Collections.Generic`), but can't seem to find anything online about the Fetch that comes after it. Also can't find anything in the `Iinfo` Interface about Fetch. Where does the `Fetch(*stuff*)` come from?

Comment: That's a custom interface, it came from where you see it.

Comment: `Fetch(*stuff*)` is just a member of `Itest` iterface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- `Iinfo` is an interface defined in your application. Click on the word `Iinfo` and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the definition.
- `Fetch` is a method defined in your interface `Itest`. If a non-abstract class wants to implement your `Itest` interface, it must implement a method `Fetch` with the given parameters, returning a `List<Entity>`.

Notes:

- The .NET naming conventions say that your interfaces should be called `IInfo` and `ITest` (PascalCase after the initial `I`), and that your parameters should be called `id`, `name` and `stateId` (camelCase).
- If you are working on this application, use this opportunity to update its documentation. Find whoever wrote `Itest` and `Iinfo`, interview them to find out what these interfaces do, and then write down your findings in *XML comments*, so that the next poor guy maintaining this app won't be in the same situation as you are now.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx), a contract of what method signatures you can expect from classes, which implement it.

Basically it says

> whatever class, which implements Itest, surely will have a method `Fetch`, which takes 3 inpout parameters and returns a List<Entity>`